# How using $pushAll in go with mgo

Tags: mongodb, go, mgo

I store like this struct

```
type Test struct {
    Key string
    Tags []string
}
```

in mongodb, Then i want update tags add some another tags, I found [$pushAll](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/pushAll/), But i can't how to using it.

I Try

```
mongoDb.C("test").Update(
    bson.M{"key": key},
    bson.M{"$set": bson.M{"tags": bson.M{"$pushAll": tags}}}
)
```

But it's error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Operators like [**`$set`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/set/) and [**`$push`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/push/) and even [**`$pushAll`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/pushAll/) define the actions for the "update" portion of the statement. These are "top level" operators so you define them at the "root" level of the update statement with the fields to operate on as it's children:

```
mongoDb.C("test").Update(
    bson.M{"key": key}, 
    bson.M{"$pushAll": bson.M{"tags": tags}}
)
```

As of MongoDB 2.6 though the `$pushAll` operator is considered deprecated. The functionality has been merged with the [**`$each`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/each/) modifier, which also works with [**`$addToSet`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/addToSet/):

```
mongoDb.C("test").Update(
    bson.M{"key": key}, 
    bson.M{"$push": bson.M{"tags": bsonM.{"$each": tags} }}
)
```

The operator is available for `$push` as of MongoDB 2.4, where the difference in latest versions being the omission of the [**`$slice`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/slice/) modifier which is also required with earlier releases. Unless you need to support legacy versions it is generally recommended to use the `$each` modifier instead for future compatibility.